# creating data frame from vectors including empty ones

Tags: r

I have vectors like below

```
country = c("A", "B", "C")
value = c("x")
price = (character 0) #empty vector
```

I need to obtain data frame like below (just merge these vectors with NA values)

```
country  value  price
A        x       NA
B        NA      NA
C        NA      NA
```

How can I bind these vector to data frame?

Comment: what about `list2DF(list(country = country, value=value, price = price))`?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
 a <- list(country = country, value=value, price = price)
 data.frame(lapply(a, `length<-`, max(lengths(a))))

  country value price
1       A     x  <NA>
2       B  <NA>  <NA>
3       C  <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `stri_list2matrix`

```
library(stringi)
out <- stri_list2matrix(list(country, value, price))
colnames(out) <- c('country', 'value', 'price')
out
#     country value price
#[1,] "A"     "x"   NA   
#[2,] "B"     NA    NA   
#[3,] "C"     NA    NA
```